# sonar Unit Test coverage percentage not showing properly

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I just implemented `Sonar` Analysis on my project. It has  `java`, `Spring`, `Hibernate` and `GWT` environment. I have written some unit test cases for the Business Layer using `Spring-Junit 4`. When i try to execute those test cases, it is working perfectly in `Eclipse`, `maven install` as well as in *Sonar Reports* as shown below:

The problem is, In Sonar Report **Unit Test Coverage** is remains **0.0%** though there was 11 test cases executed successfully. I have generated this report on *Standalone Sonar Server* using command `mvn sonar:sonar`

**Sample Test Case**

```
@RunWith(value=SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class ThresholdServicesImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private IThresholdServices thresholdServices;


        @Test
        public void testSomemethods(){
        //testing and validating the methods.
         }

}
```

**Sonar Screenshot ( Business Layer code)**

[image: screen shot of sonar for business layer module alone]

From the above screenshot, there was 11 test cases executed successfully, but that doesn't have any impact on Unit Test Coverage.

Kindly provide your suggestion to resolve this.

**NOTE:**

1. For other layer(Data and Service Layer) the unit test coverage are
   showing as   expected.
2. The total Number of Lines in this business
   layer is 2,995 and i would cover at least 500 LOC in my test
   coverage, So the percentage of Test coverage would not be negligible
   for this case.

Comment: Do you verified if the jacoco.exec file has any coverage?
You can run [this code](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ExecDump.java) and verify.